# How do I generate dynamic product descriptions based on SQL columns?

Tags: sql, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, text, dynamic

I'm looking for the best way to do the following.

I have a database of about 11.000 products, which all have different properties (color, material, length, width, category)

I would like to generate dynamic product descriptions based on the available (NOT NULL) properties in the database.

For example

PRODUCT Table

```
| ProductId | Code | MaterialId | ColorId | CategoryId |
| --------- | ---- | ---------- | ------- | ---------  |
| 1         | G5BB | 50         | NULL    | 71         |
| 2         | FF88 | 100        | 5       | 25         |
```

COLOR Table

```
| ColorId | Name  |
| ------- | ----- |
| 5       | black |
| 9       | blue  |
```

MATERIAL Table

```
| MaterialId | Name    |
| ---------- | ------- |
| 50         | steel   |
| 100        | plastic |
```

CATEGORY Table

```
| CategoryId | Name    |
| ---------- | ------- |
| 71         | bearing |
| 25         | screw   |
```

When the category is 'Bearing', I would like to show a description like
"Product *G5BB* is a *steel* bearing which is a machine element that constrains relative motion to only the desired motion, and reduces friction between moving parts."

When the category is 'Screw',  I would like to show a description like
"Product *FF88* is a screw and is made of *black* *plastic*. Screws are used to fasten materials by the engagement of the screw thread with a similar female thread (internal thread) in the matching part."

Off course I can write this text in my HTML page and put some variables in between, but I have a lot of categories and this would mean my HTML code will become HUGE with all the text and *ifs*.

I would rather like to maintain these texts in my SQL database as a column in the CATEGORY Table.
But then how do I use the dynamic fields (color, material,...) in these texts?

I think that a view in SQL is a solution, but I'm working with ASP.NET CORE MVC (Code first) and I would like to avoid building views directly in SQL.

Does anyone has an idea or solution?

Comment: Something like a lookup table of categores (you probably have this already) with the appropriate text for each with placeholders for the variable parts, and a function to replace with actual values using case expressions.

Comment: Something like: "Product [PRODUCTPLACEHOLDER] is a screw and is made of [COLORPLACEHOLDER] [MATERIALPLACEHOLDER]. Screws are used to fasten materials by the engagement of the screw thread with a similar female thread (internal thread) in the matching part. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes something like that, using `replace` to substitute actual values from the query

Answer (score 0):

You Can create Stored Procedure in SQl

`declare @Categorytype varchar(30) `(parameter of SP)`

`variable`
declare @Description varchar(MAX)
declare @ProductCode varchar(30)
declare @MaterialId  varchar(30)
declare @MaterialName  varchar(30)

Select @ProductCode = Code,@MaterialId = MaterialId from PRODUCT where CategoryId in
(Select categoryid from CATEGORY where [name] = @Categorytype)

Select  @MaterialName  =  MaterialName from MATERIAL  where MaterialId  = @MaterialId

Set @Description =  'Product '+@ProductCode+' is a '+@MaterialName+' and is made of black plastic.
Screws are used to fasten materials by the engagement of the screw
thread with a similar female thread (internal thread) in
the matching part.'`

Comment: As I wrote: I'm working with ASP.NET CORE MVC (Code first) and I would like to avoid building views directly in SQL. So also Stored Procedures.

Comment: then its good approach to use SP because if you filter data like this in code then its become so much complicated .using SP is better way for Data manipulation.